# ssh-agent reset in Windows Subsystem for linux (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I am trying to use ssh-agent under WSL but the SSH params are wiped after the script is run

From .bashrc (cut down version)

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add

ssh-add -l
echo "SSH_AGENT_PID is" $SSH_AGENT_PID
echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is" $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Prompts for the passphrase then shows the fingerprint and relevant variables

straight after at prompt (or seperate script) running

```
ssh-add -l
echo "SSH_AGENT_PID is" $SSH_AGENT_PID
echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is" $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

gives

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
SSH_AGENT_PID is
SSH_AUTH_SOCK is
```

(tidied for readability)

the agent is still running with the original pid (checked in top)
also tried `eval $(ssh-agent ) > /dev/null` and `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` and in combination

Why do these get wiped? ssh-agent worked fine until windows update 1709 "fall creators update"

for info:
linux version 4.4.0-43-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014

Repost from here:https://superuser.com/questions/1278539/ssh-agent-reset-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a late answer for anybody arriving here : https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183

Short version : ssh-agent forwarding is broken by a getsockopt bug in wsl / ubuntu 18.04 (or any other linux I would imagine).

Comment: Reported in #3183 that the issue is fixed in insiders builds. It will be pushed out to regular Windows in the Fall 2018. In the meantime, the work-around is to retrieve the ssh-agent binary from 16.04. There is a recipe how to do that in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fix on Ubuntu 18.04 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft by the following from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183#:%7E:text=Oct%208%2C%202019-,add%20these%20code%20to%20%7E/.bashrc,ssh-agent%20%5D%20%26%26%20eval%20%22%24(ssh-agent%20-s)%22%0Assh-add%20%7E/.ssh/id_rsa,-%F0%9F%91%8D%205):

```
[ -x /usr/bin/ssh-agent ] && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourseckey
```

add it to your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Actually non of the above scripts are working in WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04. The only good solution for me so far was when I simply added `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` to my `.bash_profile`.